# HQL : Named Parameter not found even if it exist

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am getting the exception could not locate named parameter even though it exists.

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [type]
```

Query

```
String query = ("insert into my_table (abc_id, dup_id,type_code) "+
                     " (abc_seq.nextval, 2,:type");
            Query myQuery = em.createNativeQuery(query);    
            nativeQuery.setParameter("type", code);
```

I simply dont understand what is the issue.

Comment: Not really a duplicate @Andremoniy but just a typo issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query lacks a parenthesis and a `values` keyword.

Try

```
String query = ("insert into my_table (abc_id, dup_id,type_code) "+
                "values (abc_seq.nextval, 2,:type)");
Query myQuery = em.createNativeQuery(query);    
nativeQuery.setParameter("type", code);
```